# Using JQuery function to filter a table in a php html file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In one of the pages in a coursework piece I am currently doing on web development, I have a table on Homepage.php in which I wish to filter the contents shown based on the option selected in a dropdown above the table. The file Utils.js contains the function typeFilter, which takes in a table name, dropdown name (referred as filtername for the meantime), and a column name in which the show() and hide() is based upon.

From a previously found stackoverflow solution on jquery table filtering, I managed to get the function working in jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/dey17o20/6/), but when trying to make it reusable in the context of my coursework it does not update the displayed table when used. I'm new to using JQuery and JS so any help in fixing this would be greatly appreciated! :)

Utils.js (Updated as per answer)

```
function typeFilter(tableName, filterName, columnName) {
    const elem = $('#' + filterName);
    elem.change(function() {
        if(elem.val() != "All"){
          $("#" + tableName + " td." + columnName + ":contains('" + elem.val() + "')").parent().show();
          $("#" + tableName + " td." + columnName + ":not(:contains('" + elem.val() + "'))").parent().hide();
        }
      else{
      $("'#" + tableName + " td." + columnName + "'").parent().show(); 
      }
      });
  };
```

Homepage.php

```
    session_start();
    require('../utilities/Config.php');
    require('../utilities/Utils.php');
    require('../model/animals.php');
    require('../model/requests.php');
    require('../utilities/Auth.php');
    usercheck();
?>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Homepage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
    <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../utilities/Utils.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <p class="tabletext"> Listed below are all animals available for adoption. </p>
        <table class="table table-striped" id="table1">
        <label for="filter1"> Filter by: </label>
        <select name='type' id="filter1" required>
            <option value='All'>All</option>
            <option value='Dog'>Dog</option>
            <option value='Cat'>Cat</option>
            <option value='Horse'>Horse</option>
            <option value='Bird'>Bird</option>
            <option value='Reptile'>Reptile</option>
        </select>
        <script language="javascript"> typeFilter('table1', 'filter1', 'col1'); </script>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Id</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Picture</th>
            <th scope="col">Type</th>
            <th scope="col">Description</th>
            <th scope="col">DOB</th>
            <th scope="col">Request Adoption</th>
        </tr>
        <?php

        $rows = Animals::listAvailable($_SESSION['username']);
        forEach($rows as $row){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
            ?>
            <tr scope='row'>
            <td><?= $row['ID'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['Name']?> </td>
            <td><img src="../uploads/<?= $row['Picture'] ?>" alt="HTML5 Icon" height="150" width="150"></td>
            <td class='col1'><?= $row['Type'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['Description'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['DOB'] ?></td>
            <td>
            <form class= 'formbox' id='adopt' action='Homepage.php' method='post'>

                <input type="hidden" name="animalID" value= "<?= $row['ID'] ?>"/>  
                <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true"/>
                <button id ='reqbutton' type='submit'  class="btn btn-warning">Request</button>
            </form>
            </td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try putting this line: <script language="javascript"> typeFilter('table1', 'filter1', 'col1'); </script> out of the table. and also omit the "language" attribute.

Comment: Put it after the table & removed the attr... still no luck. Appreciate the help thus far though! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok there are just two little mistakes in your function:

```
const elem = $(this);  // wrong
```

You do not have any reference to an object (element) at this point. So 'this' won't have any content.

In your function parameters you are passing the filter elment already... so use this instead:

```
const elem = $('#' + filterName);
```

Now you ll be able to bind the event 'change' and also get the value of the element (.val())

```
$("'#" + filterName + "'").change(function() { // wrong
```

The single quotes are messing up the element selection (atleast at my fiddle). You already declared the filter element in my first step - just use:

```
elem.change(function () {
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for the refactoring. I've gone and implemented those syntactical changes, however I still don't seem to be having much luck. Maybe it could be something in the Homepage.php thats messing it up? Anything I could do for error reporting or the like?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oafxsq7m/2/

works fine for me now. The php file seems to be ok... but hard to test by myself with all this dependencies.

*edit - try to place a console.log or alert within the change-function. check if the event is fireing.

Comment: Pasted the code from that jsfiddle, and added an alert notification. Interestingly, no alert shows when i change the dropdown, does this mean it hasnt fired?

Comment: Yes, seems there is still a problem with the element selection. Check again if the passed element id is correct.

Also put an console.log(elem) straight after the declaration and check the console output, if the correct element is selected or if its empty

Comment: Nothing seems to happen as such, so I get the feeling there may be something going on in the Homepage.php file thats stopping this function running, would my <script> tags be erroneous at all? The rest of the page content (php and the like) seem to run just fine

Comment: I tried to reproduce your environment on my local machine so I used a simple html file and copied all static content (everything expect the php generated stuff). Also created a Utils.js file and put the plain typeFilter function into it. Filtering works fine for me.

Sure you do not have any error in the browsers output console?

Comment: Aight, I have fixed it. Seems to be the url for the src for the jquery wasn't working, so I tried <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js%22%3E"</script> as it, and it started to work.

Regardless of how much of an idiot I am, I really appreciate your help in refactoring and tidying up the implentation, so thank you a lot for that

Comment: Ah great - well yea i used the cdn from jquery and worked fine :)

Comment: Seems I've another issue now, whereby on my xampp local server it runs fine, but on the host server used for our submissions, it doesnt seem to run the jquery at all EDIT: stackoverflow has blessed me again cause it was down to using http instead of https for the src

Comment: Good that it works now. By the way - my answer was not a refactoring since there was a mistake in your first implementation. $(this) will not work in your context since there was not any reference on the select-elment. The second point is just a refactoring.